# How do I aquire an encoded kerberos ticket in windows?

Tags: windows, kerberos, klist

On a windows client, I have a service ticket for a web service (I can see the ticket with klist), and I am trying to write an
app to get the encoded service ticket and pass it on to the service (over HTTPS) so that it can be decrypted with the service key.

By using the klist example provide in the windows SDK (at *\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Samples\security\authorization\klist*) I am able to get a handle to the service ticket and get a [KERB_EXTERNAL_TICKET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure that contains the
"EncodedTicket" which claims to be "*A buffer that contains the Abstract Syntax Notation One (ASN.1)-encoded ticket.*"

Is this "EncodedTicket" the ticket that I want to pass onto my webserivce? Will it still be encrypted with the service key? How do I convert this buffer into a base64 string that I can pass on to my webservice?

Comment: I'm making a call to LsaCallAuthenticationPackage()

Comment: Are you able to obtain the TGT at all?